# Using BeautifulSoup to collect urls from html code

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i have collected a list of links from a folder of documents that essentially is wikipedia pages. I eventually realized that my list of links is incomplete, because my code only collects a few of the links from each wikipedia page. My goal is to get all links and then filter it afterwards. I should end up with a list of links to train related accidents. Keywords for such accidents in the links varies between disaster, tragedy etc. i dont know them beforehand.

My input is

```
list_of_urls = []

for file in files:     
    text = open('files_overview/'+file, encoding="utf-8").read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(text, features="lxml")
    for item in soup.findAll("div", attrs={'class':'mw-content-ltr'}):                 
        url = item.find('a', attrs={'class':'href'=="accident"}): 
#If i dont add something, like "accident" it gives me a syntax error.. 
        urls= url.get("href")               
        urls1="https://en.wikipedia.org"+urls   
        list_of_urls.append(urls1)
```

HTML code from one of my documents, wherein multiple links lies are given below:

```
</div><div class="mw-category-generated" lang="en" dir="ltr"><div id="mw-pages">
<h2><span class="anchor" id="Pages_in_category"></span>Pages in category "Railway accidents in 1860"</h2>
<p>The following 3 pages are in this category, out of  3 total. This list may not reflect recent changes (<a href="/wiki/Wikipedia:FAQ/Categorization#Why_might_a_category_list_not_be_up_to_date?" title="Wikipedia:FAQ/Categorization">learn more</a>).
</p><div lang="en" dir="ltr" class="mw-content-ltr"><h3>A</h3>
<ul><li><a href="/wiki/Atherstone_rail_accident" title="Atherstone rail accident">Atherstone rail accident</a></li></ul><h3>B</h3>
<ul><li><a href="/wiki/Bull_bridge_accident" title="Bull bridge accident">Bull bridge accident</a></li></ul><h3>H</h3>
<ul><li><span class="redirect-in-category"><a href="/wiki/Helmshore_rail_accident" class="mw-redirect" title="Helmshore rail accident">Helmshore rail accident</a></span></li></ul></div>
</div></div><noscript><img src="//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:CentralAutoLogin/start?type=1x1" alt="" title="" width="1" height="1" style="border: none; position: absolute;" /></noscript>
<div class="printfooter">Retrieved from "<a dir="ltr" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Category:Railway_accidents_in_1860&amp;oldid=895698968">https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Category:Railway_accidents_in_1860&amp;oldid=895698968</a>"</div></div>
        <div id="catlinks" class="catlinks" data-mw="interface"><div id="mw-normal-catlinks"
```

From the above, i manage to get Atherstone_rail_accident, but not bull_bridge nor helmshore.
Does anyone have a better approach?

Thank you for your time

Comment: Just as you use a loop to find all the appropriate `div`s in a file, you'll need one to get all of the `a`s in a `div`.

Comment: Something like:                                                                                                               

`for file in files:    
    text = open('accident_overview/'+file, encoding="utf-8").read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(text, features="lxml")
    for item in soup.findAll("div", attrs={'class':'mw-content-ltr'}):         
        for x in item:
            url = x.find('a', attrs={'class':'href'=="accident"}) 
            urls= url.get("href")`  

I get an error. AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What happens?

You just iterate over one element from result set of `soup.findAll("div", attrs={'class':'mw-content-ltr'})`, thats why you only get the first link.

#### Example

```
list_of_urls = []
for file in files:     
    text = open('files_overview/'+file, encoding="utf-8").read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(text, features="lxml")

    for a in soup.select('div.mw-content-ltr a'):
        list_of_urls.append(f'https://en.wikipedia.org{a["href"]}')
```

#### How to fix?

Instead of selecting the `<div>` select all the links in your `<div>` and iterate over it:

```
for a in soup.select('div.mw-content-ltr a'):
    list_of_urls.append(f'https://en.wikipedia.org{a["href"]}')
```

#### Output

```
['https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atherstone_rail_accident',
 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bull_bridge_accident',
 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmshore_rail_accident']
```

### EDIT

Adding the prefix `https://en.wikipedia.org` later in the process just skip this task while appending the `href` to your list:

```
for a in soup.select('div.mw-content-ltr a'):
    list_of_urls.append(a["href"])
```

If you like to request the urls in a second step you can do it like this:

```
for url in list_of_urls:
    response = requests.get(f'https://en.wikipedia.org{url}')
```

Or if just need a list with full urls you append it with `list comprehension`:

```
list_of_urls = [f'https://en.wikipedia.org{a["href"]}' for a in list_of_urls]
```

Comment: and if i dont want to do `[href*=accident]` but i want all links? its non-responsive if i write a[href]

Comment: i dont get these from another page, for example <a href="/wiki/The_Camp_Hill_disaster" class="mw-redirect" title="The Camp Hill disaster">The Camp Hill disaster</a></span></li></ul><h3>G</h3>
<ul><li><a href="/wiki/Great_Train_Wreck_of_1856" title="Great Train Wreck of 1856">Great Train Wreck of 1856</a></li></ul><h3>P</h3>
<ul><li><span class="redirect-in-category"><a href="/wiki/The_Picnic_Train_Tragedy" class="mw-redirect" title="The Picnic Train Tragedy">The Picnic Train Tragedy</a>
<ul><li><span class="redirect-in-category"><a href="/wiki/Schiedam_train_accident"

Comment: Edited answer just use `soup.select('div.mw-content-ltr a')` to get `<a>` in div with class mw-content-ltr

Comment: works really well HedgeHog, thank you so much. Two quick questions if i can pick your brain some more. Why do you add an "f" in front of 'https://en.wikipedia.org{a["href"]}')? - Furthermore, do you have a suggestion to how i could go about appending the "'https://en.wikipedia.org" later?

Comment: `f-string` - Also called [“formatted string literals,”](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#abstract) have an f at the beginning and curly braces containing expressions that will be replaced with their values. In my opinion it looks much cleaner as the concat with `+`  **For further questions -> ask them as a new question**, so answers and comments do not get that messy :) Thanks and happy coding

Comment: Duly noted. Thank you again :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

- First find all the `<div>` with class name as `mw-content-ltr` using `.find_all()`
- For each `<div>` obtained above, find all the `<a>` tags using `.find_all()`. This will give you a list of `<a>` for each `<div>`.
- Iterate over and extract the `href` from the above list of `<a>` tags.

Here is the code.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = """
<div class="mw-category-generated" lang="en" dir="ltr">
   <div id="mw-pages">
      <h2><span class="anchor" id="Pages_in_category"></span>Pages in category "Railway accidents in 1860"</h2>
      <p>The following 3 pages are in this category, out of  3 total. This list may not reflect recent changes (<a href="/wiki/Wikipedia:FAQ/Categorization#Why_might_a_category_list_not_be_up_to_date?" title="Wikipedia:FAQ/Categorization">learn more</a>).</p>
      <div lang="en" dir="ltr" class="mw-content-ltr">
         <h3>A</h3>
         <ul>
            <li><a href="/wiki/Atherstone_rail_accident" title="Atherstone rail accident">Atherstone rail accident</a></li>
         </ul>
         <h3>B</h3>
         <ul>
            <li><a href="/wiki/Bull_bridge_accident" title="Bull bridge accident">Bull bridge accident</a></li>
         </ul>
         <h3>H</h3>
         <ul>
            <li><span class="redirect-in-category"><a href="/wiki/Helmshore_rail_accident" class="mw-redirect" title="Helmshore rail accident">Helmshore rail accident</a></span></li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<noscript><img src="//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:CentralAutoLogin/start?type=1x1" alt="" title="" width="1" height="1" style="border: none; position: absolute;" /></noscript>
<div class="printfooter">Retrieved from "<a dir="ltr" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Category:Railway_accidents_in_1860&amp;oldid=895698968">https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Category:Railway_accidents_in_1860&amp;oldid=895698968</a>"</div>
</div>
<div id="catlinks" class="catlinks" data-mw="interface">
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(s, 'lxml')

divs = soup.find_all('div', class_='mw-content-ltr')

for div in divs:
    for a in div.find_all('a'):
        print(a['href'])
```

```
/wiki/Atherstone_rail_accident
/wiki/Bull_bridge_accident
/wiki/Helmshore_rail_accident
```

Comment: why add the s = """? what does that mean?

Comment: my solution needs to be adaptable to multiple pages with different links but with same html class = 'mw-content-ltr' . If its important that i input the HTML code, it wont scale very well as i have 50+ or so pages to parse over.

Comment: worked without s = """... :-) thank you Ram!

Comment: ```s="""``` is just used to store multi line strings to a variable. Please upvote if it works.

Comment: I tried, not enough rep? Need 15 to do that. And i can only distribute one check mark, apparently... but i am grateful for your help..